Why does the maternal uncle feed the child instead of the father (as prescribed in the scripture) in the Annaprashana ceremony?
Annaprashana is one of the Samskaras that Hindu householders perform after the birth of a baby. In this ceremony, when the baby is six months old, solid food is given to him/her first time. This Samskara is very popular and widely practised in India.
The ritual procedure of performing this Samskara is mentioned in Vedangas, to be specific, in Grihyasutras. Grihyasutras are part of Kalpasutras, and Kalpasutras are part of the Vedangas. Here I am quoting from Paraskara Grihyasutra associated with the White Yajurveda.
Paraskara Grihyasutra I.19


In the sixth month the Annaprāśana (or first feeding with solid food).




Having cooked a mess of sacrificial food, and sacrificed the two Ājyabhāgas, he offers two Ājya oblations, (the first with the verse,) 'The gods have generated the goddess Speech; manifold animals speak her forth. May she, the sweet-sounding, the cow that (for milk) gives sap and juice to us, Speech, the highly-praised one, come to us. Svāhā!'




And the second (oblation) with (the verse), 'May vigour us to-day' (Vāj. Saṃhitā XVIII, 33).




He then sacrifices (four oblations) of cooked food with (the formulas),
'Through up-breathing may I enjoy food. Svāhā!
'Through down-breathing may I enjoy smells. Svāhā!
'Through my eye may I enjoy visible things. Svāhā!
'Through my ear may I enjoy renown. Svāhā!'




After he has eaten (himself), he should set apart food of all kinds, and of all different sorts of flavour, and should give it to him (i.e. to his son) to eat,




Silently or with (the word), 'Hanta' (i.e. Well!). For it is said in the Śruti, 'Men (live on) the word hanta.'




(He feeds the child) with flesh of (the bird called) Bhāradvājī, if he wishes (to the child) fluency of speech,




With flesh of partridge, if abundance of nouṛṣment,




With fish, if swiftness,




(With flesh) of (the bird) Kṛkaṣā, if long life,




(With flesh) of (the bird) Āṭi, if desirous of holy lustre,




With all, if desirous of all.




Or each (sort of) food one by one. Then (follows) feeding of the Brāhmaṇas, or each (sort of) food one by one. Then feeding of the Brāhmaṇas.


Agamas or Tantra also mention this ceremony.

O Shiva! In the sixth or eighth month either the father’s brother or the father himself should give the first rice to the child. - Mahanirvana Tantra 9.165

Thus, in both, Vedangas and Agamas, it is mentioned that the child's father should feed him/her.
Here is the confusion. In Bengal, the maternal uncle feeds the child. This is baffling. This is against Sastra and also common sense. It is the father, whose bloodline is getting continued through the child; it should be his privilege to feed the child for the first time. It is beyond my comprehension, how the maternal uncle comes into the picture. He has no business here.
My question is why this malpractice is so prevalent? Is there any Sastra that prescribes this? I doubt. I don't know what happens in the other parts of India; I would love to know.
References -

Paraskara Grihyasutra translated by Hermann Oldenberg (online, epub, pdf)
Mahanirvana Tantra translated by Arthur Avalon (online, epub, pdf)


There are multiple such 'deshachara's which can be considered as malpractices from the lens of the scriptures. Punjabi Hindus freely inter-marrying with Sikhs of the same caste, Sindhi Hindus venerating Nanak, varnasankara castes like kayasthas, abhiras etc claiming non-brahmin dvija status in the Hindi belt without performing upanayana, historical practice of polyandry among Pahari Hindus, fish consumption by Bengali, Maithili, Odiya & Axomiya Hindus & Tamil Hindus marrying their own maternal cousins - all of these violate scriptural injunctions.
